# How to observe firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName and other attributes for changes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, vuex

I am using firebase auth and when users change their profile, such as their `displayName`, `photoURL`, or `email` etc. the `onAuthStateChanged` callback won't be fired, but the underlying `firebase.auth().currentUser` gets updated automatically.

I need to update the UI after the user updates their profile, ie. I would like to keep `firebase.auth().currentUser` in sync with the client store (specifically `vuex` or `redux`-like store).

Is there a way to observe `firebase.auth().currentUser` for changes, or any other hooks I can use to get notified when `firebase.auth().currentUser` changes?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't think this feature exists at the moment. You should log a defect with the Firebase team.

Comment: You can call the function to update your ui. For example when user changes name, call the function to set the new name to your ui. if the other user changes his profile, then use database to keep the data changes and notify via ondatachange

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I get the same problem for me, I was using with react and want to see a component who changed from `Send verification Email` to `Email Verified`. What I've done it's create a function who wrap the `reload` method on the user instance. This one is a promise, so when the promise fulfilled I now call the `firebase.auth().currentUser` function who get now update cause of the reload. I match all that with some component lifecycle etc.

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
user.reload().then(() => {
  const refreshUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  // do your stuff here
})
```

The docs for the reload are there. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reload

Hope that can help :)

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any callbacks for when a Firebase Authentication user profile changes.  The typical pattern is to write the user profile data into a data store (such as Realtime Database) every time an authentication listener is triggered in a client app.  Clients can then listen to the location where profile data for each user lives, and react to those changes on their own.  Also, you can use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to write a database write trigger that can check to see if anything actually changed when profile data is written, and take action there as needed.

Comment: Make sense, this way we are good to go for getting real time updates on any changes for user data/profile/any.

Comment: the more best way is just ignore those things and setup display name, email, avatar etc in our own realtime db and use